# Drop duplicates issue Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Beginner here !
The purpose of my code:

- import csv and excel file (no issues)
- format , filter apply conditions to both (no issues)
- concatenate both df (no issues)
- remove duplicates from last df (issue)

The issue I have is no duplicates are being dropped from df2 , i am using ['Scaffold ID'] as a subset

```
**df3 sample**

  

   

 

     Scaffold ID | Supervisor | Client Requester |BLK Location  \
                 42324   Dave            Ben            11A Block   
                 42836   Dave            Ben            11A Block   
                 29601   Phil            Paul           FMT   
                 43140   Ryan            Jess           11A Block   
                 45044   Ryan            Leon           11b Block                                          
                 ...           ...              ...          ...   
                 3420    Alan            Mike           31A Block   
                 3421    Alan            Mike           31B Block   
                 3422    Alan            Mike           35A Block   
                 3461    Ryan            Ben            11A Block   
                 3463    Ryan            Kev            11b Block 
    
         [3045 rows x 18 columns]
    
    **df2 sample**
    
     
    
        Scaffold ID | Supervisor | Client Requester |BLK Location  \
                 42324   Dave            Ben            11A Block   
                 42836   Dave            Ben            11A Block   
                 29601   Phil            Paul           FMT   
                 43140   Ryan            Jess           11A Block   
                 45044   Ryan            Leon           11b Block                                          
                 ...           ...              ...          ...   
                 3420    Alan            Mike           31A Block   
                 3421    Alan            Mike           31B Block   
                 3464    Alex            Joe            56A Block   
                 3468    Paul            Lucy           42A Block   
                 3467    Tony            Adam           13b Block   
    
        [1105 rows x 6 columns]
    
         
    **Desired output**
    
    Scaffold ID | Supervisor | Client Requester |BLK Location  \
                 42324   Dave            Ben            11A Block   
                 42836   Dave            Ben            11A Block   
                 29601   Phil            Paul           FMT   
                 43140   Ryan            Jess           11A Block   
                 45044   Ryan            Leon           11b Block                                          
                 ...           ...              ...          ...   
                 3420    Alan            Mike           31A Block   
                 3421    Alan            Mike           31B Block   
                 3422    Alan            Mike           35A Block   
                 3461    Ryan            Ben            11A Block   
                 3463    Ryan            Kev            11b Block
                 3464    Alex            Joe            56A Block   
                 3468    Paul            Lucy           42A Block   
                 3467    Tony            Adam           13b Block    
    
       [3048 rows x 18 columns]



import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Task details rpt / re measure mapping rpt  path's 
df = pd.read_csv('/content/TaskDetails_rpt (3).csv')
df3 = pd.read_excel('/content/RE-Measure Mapping Report.xlsx', skiprows=1)
#print(list(df))
df2 = df[['CapeNo3', 'Supervisor', 'ClientRequester', 'Location2', 'LocationDescription', 'ErCompleteDate', 'Trade']]
# Filter trade col for Access
access_filt = df.Trade == 'Access'
is_access = pd.Series(access_filt)
df2 = df2[is_access]

# remove NaN from df2 ErCompleteDate col
df2 = df2[df2['ErCompleteDate'].notna()]

# Convert ErCompleteDate from object to datetime, Filter ErCompleteDate to last 90 days 
df2['ErCompleteDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['ErCompleteDate'],format="%d/%m/%Y")
date_range_filt = df2.ErCompleteDate > datetime.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("90day")  
df2 = df2[date_range_filt]

# rename df2 col
df2.rename(columns={'CapeNo3': 'Scaffold ID', 
                    'ClientRequester': 'Client Requester',
                    'Location2': 'BLK Location',
                    'LocationDescription': 'Location Description',
                    'ErCompleteDate': 'Erect date'}, inplace=True)
# Drop Trade from df2 
df2.drop('Trade', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Concatenate df3 and df2 and drop duplicates from df2 (assign to df4)
df4 = pd.concat([df3,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Scaffold ID'], keep='first')
df4
```

data sample (I have highlighted where df3 ends and df2 begins)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/croIA.png)

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: The sample data you included a picture of doesn't show any duplicates in the `Scaffold ID` column. Can you have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a sample of your concatenated dataframe before you do the `drop_duplicates` operation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip's